# Is there a way to cancel a Vision Framework request (VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest) once triggered?

Tags: ios, computer-vision, swift4, swift-protocols

I'm running a Vision Framework request for an iOS app like follows:

```
let textDetectionRequest = VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest(completionHandler: self.findTextBoxes)
let textDetectionHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: image, orientation: orientation, options: [:])
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
   do {
        try textDetectionHandler.perform([textDetectionRequest])
   } catch {
        print(error)
   }
}
```

It's working ok and I am using a notification/observer pattern to take further action once the request completes. There are times in the app when I need to cancel the process before the request finishes doing its thing, so are there any type of protocols/delegate methods from the Vision Framework I can use to call for cancelation?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: It’s been a while, but I recall I solved this using a state machine. I could not get the request to be cancelled, but I was able to ignore it once it finished.

Answer (score 2):

Now, all [`NVRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/vnrequest) objects have a `cancel()` method.

Comment: but VNImageRequestHandler is not a subclass of NVRequest, but just of NSObject.
Apple docs say NVRequest is "The abstract superclass for analysis requests" but VNImageRequestHandler hasn't got a cancel method

Comment: @meronix You don't cancel the `VNImageRequestHandler`. The request (e.g. `VNDetectTextRectanglesRequest`) can be cancelled.

Comment: oh ok, thanks, now I've got it, so I need to retain somewhere my array of NVRequests to cancel them